# why appending the dictionary gives key error?

Tags: python, dictionary

why appending the dictionary using m1 gives key error? even if i input 45 ,then thisdict{} becomes thisdict{45:"n"}. Then if i input 45 again in m1 , then why appending the thisdict dictionary in thisdict["m1"].append(n1)  gives key error?

```
    thisdict = {}
    m=int(input())
    n=input()
    thisdict[m]=n
    print(thisdict)
    
    m1=int(input())
    n1=input()
    thisdict["m1"].append(n1)
    print(thisdict)
```

Comment: you seem to have a typo, it should be `m1` object, currently it is `"m1"` which is a literal string.

Comment: if add  like this "add thisdict[m1].append(n1)"  then compiler gives me this error :  AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: because with `thisdict[m]=n`, `thisdict[m]` is a element of type str and not a list, you need to create a list object for the value of the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does that because m1 isn't in the dictionary.
Also you wrote "m1 " instead of m1
Key Error means that the key m1 does not exist because you try to **add** to it, not to initialize it.
You can do like that:

```
thisdict = {}
m=int(input())
n=input()
thisdict[m]=n
print(thisdict)
   
m1=int(input())
n1=input()
if m1==m:
    thisdict[m1]=[thisdict[m1],n1]
else:
    thisdict[m1] = n1
print(thisdict)
```

Comment: in this case the value of the dictionary is getting overridden . i am trying to add the name of same value. For example if m and m1 are same value but different name then both name will be store in the dictionary with the number as key.

Comment: my desired case: if m=45, n="saif" , m1=45 .n1=jordan" then  thisdict{} will be :thisdict{45:"saif", "jordan"}

Comment: Do you mean {45:["saif", "jordan"]}? becaus one key can't have more than one value. I updated my post for that.